# Shared library dependency from static library results in undefined symbol error

Tags: linux, dependencies, shared-libraries, static-libraries, linker-errors

In my project I have the following code structure:

```
src/
    simulator/
        core/
        gui/
        ...
```

I'm on Linux. I need to create a shared library for the `simulator` folder which should consist of static libraries from `core` and `gui` folders; `simulator.so = simulatorcore.a + simulatorgui.a + ...`.

I'm using a makefile of some custom format, and this is how I specify the dependencies:

*simulator/Makefile.make* - should produce the shared library

```
SHLIB = simulator

SHLIB_DEPS_simulator = \
    src/simulator/core/lib_simulatorcore \
    src/simulator/gui/lib_simulatorgui
    ...
```

*simulator/core/Makefile.make* - should produce the static library

```
LIB = simulatorcore

LIB_DEPS_simulatorcore =    \
    SimulatorData.o    \
    ...
```

The code compiles but I get this error:

> libsimulator.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN9simulator4core9someClassE

I know that linking order matters for `gcc` but when I change the order of static libraries (which I specify as dependencies for the shared library file), I get another undefined symbol, this time it says a static member definition is not found.

I `nm`ed the static and dynamic libraries. The symbol is specified with `B` in the static library (simulatorcore.a) and with 'U' in the shared library (simulator.so).

Actually, when I specify the shared library dependencies with object files like this, it works fine:

```
SHLIB = simulator

SHLIB_DEPS_simulator = \
    ./core/SimulatorData.o \
    ...
```

But this is my last resort so I'd like to have a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are clues that might help you:

- Are you generating relocatable output (-r option for gcc)? Your
  static library symbols need to be forwarded to the linker, so the
  so-called "Partial linking" might help to solve your issue.
- Your "B" looks very strange so me. "B" are for data in the uninitialized
  data section of the executable. Are you trying to export some global class
  instances from your .so instead of just functions (code in the "text"
  section: "T")? AFAIK, the layout for exporting class instances in
  dynamic libraries is not normalized, and could cause some issues.